# JSON parse a string of an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to parse this string.  I've never really used the `JSON.parse` method and feel like I'm getting nowhere with it.

```
"[{\"name\"=>\"memorial hospital\", \"number\"=>\"555-555-1212\"}, {\"name\"=>\"other name hospital\", \"number\"=>\"345-234-2342\"}, {\"name\"=>\"\", \"number\"=>\"\"}]"
```

Comment: That's not JSON. That's the result of `some_array_of_hashes.inspect`. Where are you getting that string? Can you tell the source to be more sensible?

Comment: As @muistooshort said, that isn't JSON. We can't help unless you give us correct input. As is your question is unclear (actually more like nonsense) so we need to see the real incoming JSON string. JSON is extremely easy to work with so you'd probably be helped by reading other Ruby/JSON related questions.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help.  This structure is what was being saved to the database from my form.  It turns out that I needed to serialize the output before saving.  After doing that, the string saved to the database is in proper json format (with no hash rocket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the possible work arround:

first convert it to proper json by doing:

```
s = s.gsub('=>', ':')
```

then parse it by

```
JSON.parse s
```

the output should be:

```
=> [{"name"=>"memorial hospital", "number"=>"555-555-1212"}, {"name"=>"other name hospital", "number"=>"345-234-2342"}, {"name"=>"", "number"=>""}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your string is malformed.

The JSON string wouldn't have `=>`. [The `key=>value` should look like `key:value`](http://www.json.org).

Try the following string:

```
"[{\"name\":\"memorial hospital\", \"number\":\"555-555-1212\"}, {\"name\":\"other name hospital\", \"number\":\"345-234-2342\"}, {\"name\":\"\", \"number\":\"\"}]"
```

This should work:

```
require 'json'
s = "[{\"name\":\"memorial hospital\", \"number\":\"555-555-1212\"}, {\"name\":\"other name hospital\", \"number\":\"345-234-2342\"}, {\"name\":\"\", \"number\":\"\"}]"

JSON.parse s
#  => [{"name"=>"memorial hospital", "number"=>"555-555-1212"}, {"name"=>"other name hospital", "number"=>"345-234-2342"}, {"name"=>"", "number"=>""}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to json, there are some good free online json parsers/validators you can use to test your json... 
http://json.parser.online.fr/
http://jsonlint.com/

Note, you will need to remove the escape character ('\') for these parsers to work.

In this particular case, you can fix your json text by replacing '=>' with ':' within your json text.